# After installed framework from pods, not able to import in class in Swift project,Throwing an error no such module swift import

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, objc-bridging-header

[Objective C Bridge Header - header file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd6dE.png)

Comment: Did you import frame work inside bridge header file ?

Answer (score 0):

If you install a framework via pod then you don't need to import any class or framework to bridge file. it is automatically added to your project...

Basically whenever we install any framework via pod at that time it is directly not affected in our project so you need to just build again your project after installation then import a framework.

Hope it will work.